# How to convert data-mapper in Mule ESB to many connectors to use Community Runtime?

Tags: java, xml, json, mule, mule-studio

So I did all my project using Datamappers, but I realized when I wanted to deploy that DataMapper is only available for Enterprise. So now I need to redo all my work again.

My question is, how do I convert my DataMappers to free connectors? They are always JSON to XML datamappers.

For a simple one GetContactById I do a set payload after Object to String. Like so :

```
<ns0:GetContactById xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/"><ns0:id>#[json:id]</ns0:id></ns0:GetContactById>
```

And this works but for more complicated ones where the JSON is huge and can change I do not know what to use.

Should I use JSON to XML and then XSLT or maybe build a custom transformers if I have more conditions?

For example in my OrderSave I do something special in the Date

```
output.ns1_ContactId = input.ContactId;
output.ns1_Discount = input.Discount;
output.ns1_NumberOfChild = input.NumberOfChild;
output.ns1_OrderDate = str2calendar(input.OrderDate, "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
output.ns1_OrderNumber = input.OrderNumber;
output.ns1_PaymentMethod = input.PaymentMethod;
output.ns1_SpouseName = input.SpouseName;
output.ns1_Total = input.Total;
```

And I have for each Order and for each Product.

Precisely here's what I want to accomplish :

JSON received :

```
{
    "order": {
        "Id": "112",
        "Discount": "0.000000",
        "OrderDate": "2015-03-26 15:26:38",
        "OrderNumber": "VBOKLZZZF",
        "Total": "43.810000",
        "NumberOfChild": "2",
        "PaymentMethod": 1,
        "SpouseName": "Caroline Person",
        "Products": [
            {
                "Product": {
                    "Quantity": "1",
                    "UnitPrice": null,
                    "Code": "AB20"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

JSON converted to XML to send to webservice :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ns0:SaveOrder xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
  <ns0:order>
    <ns1:Id xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Entities">112</ns1:Id>
    <ns1:Discount xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Entities">0.0</ns1:Discount>
    <ns1:NumberOfChild xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Entities">2</ns1:NumberOfChild>
    <ns1:OrderDate xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Entities">2015-03-26T15:26:38.000Z</ns1:OrderDate>
    <ns1:OrderNumber xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Entities">VBOKLZZZF</ns1:OrderNumber>
    <ns1:PaymentMethod xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Entities">1</ns1:PaymentMethod>
    <ns1:Products xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Entities">
      <ns1:Product>
        <ns1:Code>AB20</ns1:Code>
        <ns1:Quantity>1</ns1:Quantity>
      </ns1:Product>
    </ns1:Products>
    <ns1:SpouseName xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Entities">Caroline Person</ns1:SpouseName>
    <ns1:Total xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service.Entities">43.81</ns1:Total>
  </ns0:order>
</ns0:SaveOrder>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Mule ESB has native support for JSON based on Jackson that you can use. see http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Native+Support+for+JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use a `json-to-object-transformer` to create a `Map` of `Map`s representing the JSON input:

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" />
```

Then use a Groovy scripting transformer to generate the XML using its excellent Markup Builder: http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_markupbuilder

Here is a sample from [an old article I wrote a while ago](http://www.infoq.com/articles/restful-services-mule):

```
<scripting:transformer name="OrderMapToMicroformat"> 
   <scripting:script engine="groovy"> <![CDATA[ 
        def writer = new StringWriter() 
        def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer) 
        xml.order(xmlns: 'urn:acme:order:3:1') { 
          customerId(payload.clientId) 
          productId(payload.productCode) 
          quantity(payload.quantity) 
        } 
        result = writer.toString() ]]> 
    </scripting:script> 
</scripting:transformer>
```

Comment: Hello David, thank you for the help. I am a bit confused at how expression-component will help me in this situation. I see it is used to evaluate a expression. Also I do not understand why to convert JSON to Java object and re-convert it back to JSON and then to convert it in XML I suppose? I added details in my question to show precisely what I want to do. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your use case. I've reviewed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried with my simple example and it seems to be working! I guess it will work for my bigger JSON too. Thanks for the answer David.